# Show progress dialog while adding views dynamically to scrollview in android

Tags: android

In the start of an activity in `OnCreate` method, I'm trying to add some text views dynamically to a scrollview of the layout file. But during the time of this operation the screen remains blank. Is it possible to show a progress dialog when adding views dynamically to a scrollview?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for that. Please post some code you're having in your `onCreate` method at the moment.

Comment: @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.lottery);
   
  for(i  = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
          TextView txt = new TextView(this); scrolview.addView(txt);}

Answer (score 0):

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lottery);

```
    for(i  = 0; i < 20; i++) {  
         TextView txt = new TextView(this);
              scrolview.addView(txt);
          }
    }
```

The code is similar to this...can u explain how to put a progress dialog...in this sample using AsyncTask...where should i perform this operation doInBackground method or on postExecute?

Comment: enter at least 15 characters
add comment
up vote 0 down vote accept
 

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.lottery);

    for(i  = 0; i < 20; i++) {  
         TextView txt = new TextView(this);
              scrolview.addView(txt);
          }
    }

The code is similar to this...can u explain how to put a progress dialog...in this sample using AsyncTask...where should i perform this operation doInBackground method or on postExecute?